# Bug in bootstrap component drop down item Javascript change class on click

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap button component which has a default button set as 'NoPriority' when this button is clicked, you get different priorities to pick from such as 'High', 'Medium', 'Low' and 'Service Request'. When you select an option e.g. 'High' it changes the text and class to the associated one

E.g. high button is the class btn btn-danger btn-sm dropdown-toggle

When you then click on the 'High' button - you get another set of items in the drop down, I want to ensure 'NoPriority' is not in this list as once a priority is selected, it cant be changed back to 'NoPriority'.

Can someone advise where I am going wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button id='btn' type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">NoPriority</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a name="priority" data-priority="high" class="dropdown-item">High</a></li>
    <li><a name="priority" data-priority="medium" class="dropdown-item">Medium</a></li>
  <li><a name="priority" data-priority="low" class="dropdown-item">Low</a></li>
  <li><a name="priority" data-priority="servicerequest" class="dropdown-item">ServiceRequest</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
    $('a[name=priority]').on('click',function() {
    const btn = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('button');
  const selectedPrior = $(this);
  switchPriority(btn, selectedPrior);
  switchBtnStyle(btn);
});

function switchPriority(currentPriorBtn, newPriorA){
    const btnText = currentPriorBtn.text();
  const aText = newPriorA.text();
  newPriorA.text(btnText);
  currentPriorBtn.text(aText);
}

function switchBtnStyle(btn){
    const btnText = btn.text();
  btn.removeClass();
  switch(btnText){
    case 'High':
    btn.addClass('btn btn-danger btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
    break;
    case 'Low':
    btn.addClass('btn btn-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
    break;
    case 'Medium':
    btn.addClass('btn btn-warning btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
    break;
    case 'ServiceRequest':
    btn.addClass('btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
    break;
  }
}
```

jfiddle if helpful: https://jsfiddle.net/9ghx291f/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove it from the list, then do so after the change:

```
$('a[name=priority]').on('click',function() {
  const btn = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('button');
  const selectedPrior = $(this);

  switchPriority(btn, selectedPrior);
  switchBtnStyle(btn);

  // remove it after switching.
  if (selectedPrior.text() === 'NoPriority') {
    selectedPrior.remove();
  }
});
```

Or as a plugin.

```js
(function( $ ) {

  $.fn.PriorityBtn = function() {
    var events = function() {
      $('a[name=priority]').on('click', switchBtn);
    };

    var switchBtn = function () {
      let btn = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('button');
      let selectedPrior = $(this);

      switchPriority(btn, selectedPrior);
      switchBtnStyle(btn);

      if (selectedPrior.text() === 'NoPriority') {
        selectedPrior.remove();
      }
    };

    var switchPriority = function (currentPriorBtn, newPriorA){
      const btnText = currentPriorBtn.text();
      const aText = newPriorA.text();
      newPriorA.text(btnText);
      currentPriorBtn.text(aText);
    };

    var switchBtnStyle = function (btn) {
      const btnText = btn.text();
      btn.removeClass();
      switch(btnText){
        case 'High':
        btn.addClass('btn btn-danger btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
        break;
        case 'Low':
        btn.addClass('btn btn-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
        break;
        case 'Medium':
        btn.addClass('btn btn-warning btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
        break;
        case 'ServiceRequest':
        btn.addClass('btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle');
        break;
      }
    };
    
    events();

    return this;
  };

}( jQuery ));

// attach to all buttons
$('.priority-btn').PriorityBtn()
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
<button id='btn' type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle priority-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">NoPriority</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a name="priority" data-priority="high" class="dropdown-item">High</a></li>
    <li><a name="priority" data-priority="medium" class="dropdown-item">Medium</a></li>
  <li><a name="priority" data-priority="low" class="dropdown-item">Low</a></li>
  <li><a name="priority" data-priority="servicerequest" class="dropdown-item">ServiceRequest</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
<button id='btn' type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle priority-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">NoPriority</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a name="priority" data-priority="high" class="dropdown-item">High</a></li>
    <li><a name="priority" data-priority="medium" class="dropdown-item">Medium</a></li>
  <li><a name="priority" data-priority="low" class="dropdown-item">Low</a></li>
  <li><a name="priority" data-priority="servicerequest" class="dropdown-item">ServiceRequest</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
<button id='btn' type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle priority-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">NoPriority</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a name="priority" data-priority="high" class="dropdown-item">High</a></li>
    <li><a name="priority" data-priority="medium" class="dropdown-item">Medium</a></li>
  <li><a name="priority" data-priority="low" class="dropdown-item">Low</a></li>
  <li><a name="priority" data-priority="servicerequest" class="dropdown-item">ServiceRequest</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
<button id='btn' type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle priority-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">NoPriority</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a name="priority" data-priority="high" class="dropdown-item">High</a></li>
    <li><a name="priority" data-priority="medium" class="dropdown-item">Medium</a></li>
  <li><a name="priority" data-priority="low" class="dropdown-item">Low</a></li>
  <li><a name="priority" data-priority="servicerequest" class="dropdown-item">ServiceRequest</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```